# Symfony : eating all my ram when fetching from postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, ubuntu

first of all this is what i am using :

- KDE neon User Edition 5.20 (Ubuntu 20.04)
- symfony CLI v4.21.3
- php v7.4.3
- PostgreSQL v12.5

Apache2 is also installed but i'm using the symfony local server.
Apache2 and PostgreSQL are disabled, i start them whenever i want to work on this project.

I had no problem while creating my entities and migrations using `php bin/console`.
And the `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` command created my tables correctly.
I had no problem inserting data to my tables.

I got two different tables :

- [Room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vngg.png)
- [User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ROLe.png)

They are in the public schema of my database and they currently have respectively 2 and 6 rows.

I am trying to run the following code in my controller just to test :

```php
class MainController extends AbstractController {
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     */
    public function index(): Response {
        $room = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Room::class)->find(1);

        var_dump($room);

        return $this->render("main/index.html.twig", [
            "controller_name" => "welcome"
        ]);
    }
}
```

And for some reason when trying to load this page on my browser, symfony eats all my ram. If i don't close the tab or stop the local server my computer starts to slow down because the ram is full.

[My poor RAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94fa1.png)

Also i tried simply using :

```php
$room = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Room::class)->findAll();
```

And i get the same problem.
But when trying to fetch something that does not exist everything works fine.

```php
$room = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Room::class)->find(999);
```

Is it something from my setup ? Or postgresql ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the Room object is too large and contains dependant objects as well, so your browser is struggling to display a very large amount of data. I would suggest to use the [VarDumper component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html) instead of var_dump. It's more efficient in terms of surfacing large objects with internal references and recursion.

```
dump($room);
```

Comment: Yeah my bad i forgot that var_dump would display everything from my class.This is pretty embarassing.

Thank you for the clarification.